# How to stop vue cli building the "report.html"?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

Vue CLI v3 always creating "dist/report.html" when building for production. It's a webpack bundle analyzer report.

I can't find a way to stop building that file.

How to avoid creating "report.html" when building Vue CLI 3 app for production?

Here is my package.json scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run serve",
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "test:e2e": "vue-cli-service test:e2e",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit"
  },
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I generated a project and built with `vue create tmp1`, *(choose default options)*, `cd tmp1 && yarn build`. What are the steps to create your project and run the build?

Comment: @tony19 I did the same couple of weeks ago - `vue create tmp1`. The report was always there. Not sure what the hell is going on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So far the only way I found to disable it is via `vue.config.js`:

```
pluginOptions: {
    webpackBundleAnalyzer: {
        analyzerMode: "disabled"
    }
},
```

Would be good to know why this thing is always on in Vue CLI 3.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to share some updates as of Vue CLI 3.8.4:

### Vue CLI

- `webpack-bundle-analyzer` is a dependency of `@vue/cli-service@^3.9.0`
- By the default, `vue-cli-service build` does not generate `dist/report.html` nor `dist/report.json`
- According to [Vue CLI documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html#vue-cli-service-build):

  - `--report` generates the `dist/report.html`
  - `--report-json` generates the `dist/report.json`. By the way, this JSON file can quickly become huge
  - Both argument can be cumulated (both `report.html` and `report.json` are generated). When I tested, cumulating both arguments make the build time significantly longer

### Webpack bundle analyser

The Vue CLI does not automatically run a web server to preview the report files. If you want to the [`webpack-bundle-analyzer` in the standard way](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer), the webpack configuration has to be updated:

```js
// in {root folder}/vue.config.js
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require("webpack-bundle-analyzer")
  .BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()]
  }
};
```

Even without the `--report` nor `--report-json`, the `report.html` will always be generated and the 8888 port should be available as `http://localhost:8888` will be prompted

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `build` npm script does not contain the `--report` parameter.

```
"scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "report": "vue-cli-service build --report",
}
```